# Beautful Soup find buttons inside div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to find the text inside each button of the table. I want to parse each sub table individually so I want to know the correspondant button to separate each table.

For now, I have this:

```
default_url = 'https://fbref.com'
url = default_url + row['squad_href']
res = requests.get(url)
## The next two lines get around the issue with comments breaking the parsing.
comm = re.compile("<!--|-->")
soup = BeautifulSoup(comm.sub("",res.text),'lxml')
info = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "sub_section_heading"}) #my button class
```

this returns:

```
[<div class="sub_section_heading"> <button class="sr_preset tooltip visible active" data-hide="[id^=all_stats_standard_ks]" data-show="#all_stats_standard_ks_3232" id="button_stats_standard_ks_3232" onclick="setTimeout(function(){sr_st_construct_stats_table_features('stats_standard_ks_3232'); }, 100);" type="button">Premier League</button>
<button class="sr_preset tooltip visible" data-hide="[id^=all_stats_standard_ks]" data-show="#all_stats_standard_ks_2901" id="button_stats_standard_ks_2901" onclick="setTimeout(function(){sr_st_construct_stats_table_features('stats_standard_ks_2901'); }, 100);" type="button">Europa League</button>
<button class="sr_preset tooltip visible" data-hide="[id^=all_stats_standard_ks]" data-show="#all_stats_standard_ks_8833" id="button_stats_standard_ks_8833" onclick="setTimeout(function(){sr_st_construct_stats_table_features('stats_standard_ks_8833'); }, 100);" type="button">EFL Cup</button>
<button class="sr_preset tooltip visible" data-hide="[id^=all_stats_standard_ks]" data-show="#all_stats_standard_ks_5591" id="button_stats_standard_ks_5591" onclick="setTimeout(function(){sr_st_construct_stats_table_features('stats_standard_ks_5591'); }, 100);" type="button">FA Cup</button>
<button class="sr_preset tooltip visible" data-hide="[id^=all_stats_standard_ks]" data-show="#all_stats_standard_ks_combined" id="button_stats_standard_ks_combined" onclick="setTimeout(function(){sr_st_construct_stats_table_features('stats_standard_ks_combined'); }, 100);" type="button">All Competitions</button>
</div>
```

I want something that returns an array with the name of every button, in this case would be something like this: `[ 'Premier League', 'Europa League', 'EFL Cup', 'FA Cup', 'All Competitions']`

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting divs when actually you are interested in the values contained in buttons within those divs. The first job would be to get the buttons. To do this let's change the select

```
info = soup.select(".sub_section_heading button")
```

This gets all buttons contained in a div with the class `.sub_section_heading`.

From here you want to generate a list with just the text contained in the button, a bit of list comprehension will help here.

```
button_texts = [x.text for x in info]
```

`button_texts` will be a list with just the button titles, but there may be repeats if there are multiple div. To make the list distinct use

```
distinct_texts = list(set(button_texts))
```

Full code for this is below.

```
default_url = 'https://fbref.com'
url = default_url + row['squad_href']
res = requests.get(url)
## The next two lines get around the issue with comments breaking the parsing.
comm = re.compile("<!--|-->")
soup = BeautifulSoup(comm.sub("",res.text),'lxml')
info = soup.select(".sub_section_heading button")
button_texts = [x.text for x in info]
distinct_texts = list(set(button_texts))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, it does not work quite well. It returns all the combinations of buttons for all the tables and I just want the buttons of *one* table since it repeats for the other ones.

Comment: I've updated the answer to account for this. Use `distinct_texts = list(set(button_texts))` to remove duplicates :)

Comment: You could also just use the findall from the original and then apply this answers select to it

Comment: Still not what I am looking for. It changes the order of the buttons and I want to keep them as they are. The buttons repeat for all the tables in the page so the buttons for the first one would be enough. Thank you for your effort and sorry if I am not being too clear